# When is multiple-window in one tmux session more appropriate than multiple tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I can't figure out when multiple-window in one tmux session is more appropriate than  multiple tmux session. If I need multiple "window" in one tmux session I always use multiple-pane instead.

So I was wondering is there some "real" use case for multiple-window in one tmux session or it just provides as *there is more than one way to do things*?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would fit Superuser better or not. I will give this a shot:

1. Space: Sometimes there's not enough screen real estate to fit the apps in the panes as you'd like
2. Prioritization: This is purely subjective, for me the 1st window is where the critical work happens.
3. Separation of concerns:

   - Frontend / backend
   - Development and build servers (e.g. celery) where the output isn't interesting
   - Temporary topics: e.g. customizing *~/.dotfiles* to customize thing

Personally I keep these in my first window:

1. Editor (main pane)
2. Shell (for commands)
3. Builder (webpack, rollup, etc)
4. HTTP Server (for logs and restarting it as needed)

In the 2nd window, optional stuff: tunnels, celery / rq / whatever job server / log tailing. They don't crash as often and their logs aren't as interesting.

The above would be too much to fit in a single window. Or it would be super noisy.

I use 2 windows to separate development from documentation in my software projects. As an example, vcspull: [session file](https://github.com/vcs-python/vcspull/blob/v1.13.0a2/.tmuxp.yaml) (Disclosure: I am creator of [tmuxp](https://tmuxp.git-pull.com/), which launches tmux sessions in `.tmuxp.yaml` files).

Further, I join interdependent projects to the same tmux session in separate windows. e.g. using [`pip install -e ../otherproject`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/#editable-installs), [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link), or [`yarn link`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link). e.g. when developing a django project, I may keep a package I'm writing a fix for in the other window so I can restart the server and see the changes relatively fast.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Sharing session could be a use case for multi-window, but your other examples why not just multi-session ?

Comment: I do use multiple sessions as well, if they're totally independent projects.  I wouldn't use a separate session for the other examples if I felt the projects are connected / similar. In my setup, it's extra effort to switch sessions, e.g. I set `tmux choose-tree -Zs` to `bind-key s`, but window switching is instant: e.g. `bind-key 1`, `bind-key 2` maps to `tmux select-window -t :=1`, `tmux select-window -t :=2`... so on. And `bind-key n` to `tmux next-window`. I think it takes time to develop a workflow and it depends on the projects you work / how you get into a groove.